# How to use SSR data fetching in nextjs with apollo client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am try to use `apollo-client` with nextjs. Here I want to fetch data in `getServerSideProps`. Suppose I have 2 components and one page-

`section.tsx` this is component-1

```
const Section = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Section
        </div>
    );
};
export default Section;
```

`mobile.tsx` this is component 2

```
const Mobile = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Mobile
        </div>
    );
};
export default Mobile;
```

Now I call this two component into home page.

`index.tsx`-

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <Container disableGutters maxWidth="xxl">
      <Section />
      <Mobile />
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({ query: GET_USER_LIST })
  return { props: {} }
}
```

Here you can see that in `getServerSideProps` I already fetch my data.

My question is How can I directly access this data form `Section` component and `Mobile` component without passing props. I don't want to pass props, because if my component tree will be more longer, then it will be difficult to manage props.

From `appollo` docs, I alreay know that `apollo client` do the same with `redux` state manager. So please tell me how can I access this data from any component that already fetched in `getServerSideProps`. Is it possible?. If not then how can what is the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `context` api if you want to avoid prop drilling? By putting data into context, you can access it from any child component. Get the data from the SSR and put it into the context.

Below is the example

```
import React, {createContext, useContext} from "react";

export default function Home({data}) {
    return <DataContext.Provider value={{data}}>
        <div>
            <Section/>
            <Mobile/>
        </div>
    </DataContext.Provider>
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const data = 'hello world' //Get from api
    return {
        props: {data},
    }
}

function Section() {
    return <div>
        Section
    </div>
}

function Mobile() {
    const context = useContext(DataContext);
    return <div>
        Mobile {context.data}
    </div>
}

const DataContext = createContext({});
```

Now, as long as your tree structure grows within the `DataContext` provider, each child node will have access to data in the context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have any example?